# Theorem 12.3 from Matsumura

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

**Theorem 12.3** (p. 87), *Commutative Ring Theory* by Matsumura.

> Let $A$ be a Krull ring, $K$ its field of fractions, and $\mathfrak{p}$ a height $1$ prime ideal of $A$; then if $\mathcal{F} = \{R_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is a family of DVRs of $K$ defining $A$, we must have $A_\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{F}$. If we set $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{A_\mathfrak{p} | \mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec} \space A \space \text{and} \space \text{ht} \space \mathfrak{p} =1\}$ then $\mathcal{F}_0$ i sa defining family of $A$. Thus $\mathcal{F}_0$ is the minimal defining family of DVRs of $A$.

I got stuck in two places while reading this proof. I will provide the proof below in case anyone wants to see it.

**Question 1**

I'm not really sure why the following two statements are equivalent:

1) for $a, b \in A$ with $a \not= 0 $, $b \in aA_\mathfrak{p}$ for all $A_\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{F_0} \implies b \in aA$

2) $aA$ can be written as the intersection of height $1$ primary ideals.

**Question 2**

Suppose that for $x \in K$, there exists $ 0 \not=a \in A$ such that $ax^n \in A$ for all $n>0$. Then, if $A$ is Noetherian, $x$ must be integral over $A$. (I want to prove this to understand the very last part where it says that $A$ is completely integrally closed).

**Proof From the Textbook**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @user26857 Basically this is what I was thinking: We need to prove that $b/a$ is integral over $A$, and since $A$ is integrally closed (being the intersection of DVR's which are integrally closed), this will imply that $b/a$ is in $A$. Every DVR is Noetherian. So since $b/a$ is almost integral over $R_i$, it must be integral over $R_i$. Since $A$ is the intersection of these, then $b/a$ is integral over $A$. But I'm not sure about the last part...am I wrong?

Comment: I still don't get it: do you know that a DVR is completely integrally closed or not?

Comment: @user26857 Sorry for the confusion...no I do not know if a DVR is completely integrally closed or not. But if I can prove that, then I will understand why *A* is completely integrally closed (by the argument in my comment), right? However, since a DVR is Noetherian, it suffices to prove that for a Noetherian ring an almost integral element is integral (which is part of exerciese 9.4 but not all of it). We already know that a DVR is integrally closed, so if almost integral implies integral then a DVR must be completely integrally closed.

Comment: @user26857 These are just my thoughts for proving that $A$ is completely integrally closed...I don't know, I could be on the wrong track.

Comment: You are on a right track, but it's too complicated. Of course, all the results you want to prove hold true, but they are not really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily seen that $2)\Rightarrow 1)$ (and this is all that matters for the proof): Suppose that $aA$ is a finite intersection of primary ideals whose radicals are height one primes. For such a prime $p$, from $b\in aA_p$ we get an $s_p\in A-p$ such that $s_pb\in aA$. In particular, $s_pb$ belongs to the primary ideal in the primary decomposition of $aA$ whose radical is $p$, say $q$, so $b\in q$ and thus it follows $b\in aA$.

To finish the proof you actually need to show that every Krull domain is completely integrally closed. This follows easily if you can prove that every DVR is completely integrally closed. Say $A$ is a DVR, and let's prove that $A$ is completely integrally closed. Consider $x\in K-A$ such that there is $0\ne a\in A$ with $ax^n\in A$ for all $n\ge1$. Then $x^{-1}\in A$. Let $t$ be a uniformizing parameter for $A$. Then $x^{-1}=ut^m$, where $u$ is invertible and $m\ge 1$. Then $x=u^{-1}t^{-m}$. Write $a=vt^r$, $v$ invertible and $r\ge0$. We get $ax^n=u^{-n}vt^{r-mn}\in A$ for all $n\ge1$, and this entails $t^{r-mn}\in A$ for all $n\ge1$, a contradiction.